# Custom validation in MVC not executing on partial views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, custom-validators

So I have file uploading input which is strongly typed and below is the `model class`

```
public class UploadImageAlbum
{
    [CustomFileValidator]
    public HttpPostedFileBase Images { get; set; }
}
```

and my `CustomFileValidator` class is as below:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property,AllowMultiple =true,Inherited =false)]
public class CustomFileValidator : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
    {
        const int maxContent = 1024 * 1024 * 50;//50 MB
        var sAllowedExt = new string[] { ".jpg", ".png" };
        var file = value as HttpPostedFileBase;
        //Check for null
        if (file == null)
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Please select an image to upload");
        }

        //Check for File Extension
        if (sAllowedExt.ToList().Contains(file.FileName.Substring(file.FileName.LastIndexOf('.'))))
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Please Upload a valid file of type : " + string.Join(",", sAllowedExt));
        }

        //Check for length of file
        if(file.ContentLength>maxContent)
        {
            return new ValidationResult("File is too large, maximum allowed size is :" + (maxContent / 1024) + "MB");
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

and my `partialview` is as below:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadImages", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { id = "frmUploadImages", novalidate = "novalidate", autocomplete = "off", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
      <div class="form-group">
            <span class="btn btn-default btn-file-img">
                  Browse @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UIAModel.Images, new { type = "file", multiple = "multiple", data_charset = "file" })
            </span>&nbsp;
            <span class="text-muted" id="filePlaceHolder">No files selected</span>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.UIAModel.Images, null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "invalid" })
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <button class="btn btn-primary addImage pull-right">
             <i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Upload
         </button>
      </div>
}
```

and below is how I load `partialview` on `click` of a `link`:

```
$('#page-inner').empty().load('/Admin/GetMediaUploadView', function () {
      $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('form#frmUploadImages'));
      //Apply client validation for partialviews
})
```

But even after following all the steps, it isn't displaying any message and point to note is, if I add `[Required]` attribute for the same, it will work well, but custom validation what I have never displays any message. What else I have to add to make this `CustomValidator` to work? I followed **[this post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1810214.aspx?Custom%20Validation%20do%20not%20work%20in%20partial%20views)** but still could not be of much help. Also if anyone let me know how to update this `model` so as to accept multiple images, it will be of great help.

Comment: Downvote?? Care to drop a comment atleast.. :/

Comment: Are you expecting client side validation?

Comment: Your attribute does not implement `IClientValidatable` which is needed for client side validation. You also need a script to add a method/rules to jquery.validate. Refer [this article](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2) for a guide

Comment: Awesome @StephenMuecke.. It was there in the post I linked above, but without much explanations.. Thanks for this.. :) If you post it as answer with some modifications, or explanations, then I shall accept it.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get client side validation, your attribute must

1. implement [IClientValidatable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iclientvalidatable(v=vs.118).aspx) which will add the associated
   `data-val-*` attributes to you html, and
2. you must include scripts to add methods to the jQuery validator.

[This article](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2) is a good guide to creating custom client and server side validation attributes.

Note also your current attribute is rather limited in that the file types and size are fixed, and it would be more flexible to include properties to specify the file types and maximum file size so that you could use it as (say)

```
[FileValidation(MaxSize="1024", FileType="jpg|png")]
public HttpPostedFileBase Images { get; set; }
```

[This article](http://blog.2mas.xyz/creating-custom-unobtrusive-file-extension-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3-and-jquery/) provide an example of an attribute that validates the file type, but could be adapted to include the `MaxSize` property.

Side note: If your loading dynamic content, then you should first set the validator to `null`

```
var form = $('form#frmUploadImages');
form.data('validator', null);
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
```

Comment: This is so handy, now I understand this form of validation. Thanks for the simple yet concise explanation :)