# FileExtension Validation using custom validation creates duplicate and invalid data-* attributes

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

This question raises after what I've tried from the answer mentioned in **<kbd>[my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33320969/custom-validation-in-mvc-not-executing-on-partial-views)</kbd>**. I followed <kbd>**[this article](http://blog.2mas.xyz/creating-custom-unobtrusive-file-extension-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3-and-jquery/)**</kbd> exactly the same way but validations for `image files` instead of `doc files` mentioned in the article.

**Description:** I have a `input` control of `type=file` which is to upload image files and this exists in one of the `partialview`. The `partialview` gets loaded on `click` of a `button`. And to apply `validations` mentioned in `model`, explicitly add `unobtrusive` to the `form`. But after following all the set-ups mentioned in the above-said article, I am not able to validate the file on `submit` also the the `data-*` created by `unobtrusive validation` is quite fishy or better say invalid. Below is the code to show how my setup looks like and here is the `html` which gets created by unobtrusive validation with invalid `data-*` attribute, may be because of which the validation fails to happen.

```
<input data-charset="file" data-val="true" data-val-fileextensions="" data-val-fileextensions-fileextensions="png,jpg,jpeg" id="File" multiple="multiple" name="File" type="file" value="">
```

**Load Partial View Js**

```
$('.getpartial').on('click', function () {
    $('.loadPartial').empty().load('/Home/GetView',function () {
        var form = $('form#frmUploadImages');
        form.data('validator', null);
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
        $(function () {
            jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('fileextensions', ['fileextensions'], function (options) {
                var params = {
                    fileextensions: options.params.fileextensions.split(',')
                };
                options.rules['fileextensions'] = params;
                if (options.message) {
                    options.messages['fileextensions'] = options.message;
                }
            });

            jQuery.validator.addMethod("fileextensions", function (value, element, param) {
                var extension = getFileExtension(value);
                var validExtension = $.inArray(extension, param.fileextensions) !== -1;
                return validExtension;
            });

            function getFileExtension(fileName) {
                var extension = (/[.]/.exec(fileName)) ? /[^.]+$/.exec(fileName) : undefined;
                if (extension != undefined) {
                    return extension[0];
                }
                return extension;
            };
        }(jQuery));
    })
})
```

**ModelClass**

```
public class ImageUploadModel
{
    [FileValidation("png|jpg|jpeg")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@model ProjectName.Models.ImageUploadModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadImages", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { id = "frmUploadImages", novalidate = "novalidate", autocomplete = "off", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
            Browse @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new { type = "file", multiple = "multiple", data_charset = "file" })
        </span>&nbsp;
        <span class="text-muted" id="filePlaceHolder">No files selected</span>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.File, null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "invalid" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary addImage pull-right">
            <i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Upload
        </button>
    </div>
}
```

and finally my **CustomFileValidation** class

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class FileValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private List<string> ValidExtensions { get; set; }

    public FileValidationAttribute(string fileExtensions)
    {
        ValidExtensions = fileExtensions.Split('|').ToList();
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase file = value as HttpPostedFileBase;
        if (file != null)
        {
            var fileName = file.FileName;
            var isValidExtension = ValidExtensions.Any(y => fileName.EndsWith(y));
            return isValidExtension;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientFileExtensionValidationRule(ErrorMessage, ValidExtensions);
        yield return rule;
    }
}
public class ModelClientFileExtensionValidationRule : ModelClientValidationRule
{
    public ModelClientFileExtensionValidationRule(string errorMessage, List<string> fileExtensions)
    {
        ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
        ValidationType = "fileextensions";
        ValidationParameters.Add("fileextensions", string.Join(",", fileExtensions));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your 2 `jQuery.validator` and the `getFileExtension()` functions should not be inside the `$('.getpartial').on('click', function () {` - move them to before the method (everything inside and including `$(function () { .... }(jQuery));`

Comment: Also that code will only validate one file so it probably will not work with `multiple="multiple"` (although it could be modified to do so)

Comment: @StephenMuecke.. Wonderful.. That did the trick.. However, the `data-*` attribute i.e. `data-val-fileextensions="" data-val-fileextensions-fileextensions="png,jpg,jpeg"` still remains same in the `DOM`..  Isn't that `invalid`?

Comment: `data-val-fileextensions-fileextensions="png,jpg,jpeg"` is generated because of the `ModelClientFileExtensionValidationRule()` method which has `ValidationType = "fileextensions";` and ` ValidationParameters.Add("fileextensions", ..)` - its a bit confusing because they should be different names. And `data-val-fileextensions=""` is because you do not have an error message.

Comment: I'll add an answer a bit later explaining why (and the potential issues with `multiple="multiple"`)

Comment: Sure @StephenMuecke.. will wait.. also as an optional I would be more glad if you also add `filesize` length check in your answer using the same custom validation.. :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke.. Also **[this article](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/handling-multiple-validation-rules-in-aspnet-mvc-using-dataannotations-and-unobtrusive-jquery-validator---part-2)** shows how to add list of validations, but again its totally bouncing above my head.. :( Tried many things but finding it difficult to understand itself.. :(

Comment: The answer is tool long already, but [this article](http://www.bradwestness.com/2014/09/24/client-side-file-upload-validation/) is worth studying for the `FileSizeAttribute`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the block code

```
$(function () {
  ....
}(jQuery));
```

from inside the `$('.getpartial').on(..)` function to before it so that its is

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    ....
  }(jQuery));

  $('.getpartial').on('click', function () { // or just $('.getpartial').click(function() {
    $('.loadPartial').empty().load('/Home/GetView',function () { // recommend .load('@Url.Action("GetView", "Home")', function() {
      var form = $('form#frmUploadImages');
      form.data('validator', null);
      $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Currently your load the content, re-parse the validator and then add add the methods to jquery validation but its to late (the validator has already been parsed)

Sidenote: You do not need to wrap the validation functions in `$(function () {`. It can be deleted and simply use `$.validator...` instead of `jQuery.validator....` as your doing elsewhere in your code.

As for the 'fishy' `data-val-*` attributes, that is exactly what your code generates. Your generating a `ClientValidationRule` named `fileextensions` (the `ValidationType = "fileextensions";` code) and then you add a property of it also named `fileextensions` (the `ValidationParameters.Add("fileextensions", ..)` code which generates `data-val-fileextensions-fileextensions="png,jpg,jpeg"`. As for `data-val-fileextensions=""`, that is generated to store the error message but you have not generated one so its an empty string.

I would suggest a few changes to your code.

1. Rename it to `FileTypeAttribute` so that you have the flexibility to
   add other file validation attributes, for example
   `FileSizeAttribute` to validate the maximum size.
2. In the constructor, generate a default error message, for example
   add `private const string _DefaultErrorMessage = "Only the following file types are allowed: {0}";` and in the last line of the constructor include `ErrorMessage = string.Format(_DefaultErrorMessage, string.Join(" or ", ValidExtensions));`
3. Change `ValidationParameters.Add("fileextensions", ...)` to (say)
   `ValidationParameters.Add("validtypes", ...)` so it generates
   `data-val-fileextensions-validtypes="png,jpg,jpeg"` which is a bit
   more meaningful (note you will need to change the script to
   `...add('fileextensions', ['validtypes'], function() ....`

**Edit**

Your code will not work with `<input type="file" multiple="multiple" ... />` In order to do so your property needs to be `IEnumerable` (note a few minor changes to your code)

```
[FileType("png, jpg, jpeg")]
public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Files { get; set; }
```

Then the validation attribute needs to check each file in the collection

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class FileTypeAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private const string _DefaultErrorMessage = "Only the following file types are allowed: {0}";
    private IEnumerable<string> _ValidTypes { get; set; }

    public FileTypeAttribute(string validTypes)
    {
        _ValidTypes = validTypes.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim().ToLower());
        ErrorMessage = string.Format(_DefaultErrorMessage, string.Join(" or ", _ValidTypes));
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files = value as IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>;
        if (files != null)
        {
            foreach(HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
            {
                if (file != null && !_ValidTypes.Any(e => file.FileName.EndsWith(e)))
                {
                    return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessageString);
                }
            }
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ValidationType = "filetype",
            ErrorMessage = ErrorMessageString
        };
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("validtypes", string.Join(",", _ValidTypes));
        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

And finally the script needs to check each file

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('filetype', ['validtypes'], function (options) {
    options.rules['filetype'] = { validtypes: options.params.validtypes.split(',') };
    options.messages['filetype'] = options.message;
});

$.validator.addMethod("filetype", function (value, element, param) {
    for (var i = 0; i < element.files.length; i++) {
        var extension = getFileExtension(element.files[0].name);
        if ($.inArray(extension, param.validtypes) === -1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
});

function getFileExtension(fileName) {
    if (/[.]/.exec(fileName)) {
        return /[^.]+$/.exec(fileName)[0].toLowerCase();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Alright buddy.. I understand.. Will do all the changes and thanks for `FileSizeValidation` link.. also You said you would be mentioning about multiple file upload handling.. Can you please show the same if possible?

Comment: The first issue is that your property is `HttpPostedFileBase` not `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>`. Then there is the issue that the `IsValid()` method is also based on one file (not multiple) and the script is also validating one file (not looping through each file). No time time but I'll play around with it tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: Sure bro.. Thank you so much.. I will also try my best to solve it.. :)

Comment: See update (combines some of the suggestions I made previously)

Comment: One small doubt, when I say `public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Files { get; set; }` how to create a strongly typed view for this?

Comment: `public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Files { get; set; }` needs to be a property of your `ImageUploadModel` model (instead of your current `public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }`) and then in the view use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Files, new { type = "file", multiple = "multiple" })`

Comment: Oh..  As simple as that.. Thank you so much Stephen... :)