# Create partial view for reusable form controls

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, partial-views

In a lof of my .NET Core MVC forms, I have code like this for every text field:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-form-label" asp-for="Field1">Field 1</label>
     <input asp-for="Field1" class="form-control" tabindex="1" autofocus />
     <span asp-validation-for="Field1" class="text-danger small"></span>
</div>
```

This code is always the same and I was wondering if I could create a partial view that I can re-use every time I wanted to place a text field on a form.

My end goal would be something like this: (pseudo-code)

```
  @Html.RenderPartial("TextField", Model.Field1)
  @Html.RenderPartial("TextField", Model.Field2)
```

Any validation attributes on `Field1` or `Field2` would still have to work though. How would I go about passing this information on? Is there a way?

Comment: Sounds like a job for editor templates? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33320969/custom-validation-in-mvc-not-executing-on-partial-views